# Implementing BRDF in R

Tags: r, software-recommendations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, reflectance

I use UAS to survey vegetation at subcentimeter resolution for my research and have found that bidirectional reflectance (BR) is a huge issue that impacts the reliability of estimates across subsequent flights. (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1161030115300733)

There are solutions for this in the world of remote sensing, specifically the bidirectional reflectance distribution function (BRDF). (https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/10/9/1348/pdf)

Is there any existing package that facilitates the use of BRDF on raster files in R?

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about R, Python or matlab in this particular question.

Comment: Thanks. I made it specific to R since I think it may be the most likely candidate.